# 404: NOT_FOUND - Meteor Vercel Deploy

Tags: meteor, vercel

After deploying to Vercel hosting I am getting this error: https://vercel.com/docs/errors/platform-error-codes#not_found

I don't know if Vercel supports meteor hosting. I have already tried adding a vercel.json file with the following code:

```
{
    "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/index.html" }]
}
```

Comment: How did you actually deploy? Can you please add a more detailed deployment process, including all involved steps and configurations (please remove secrets and sensitive information).

Comment: I used vercel deploy